# Coloring Shapes in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, graphics

So I'm working on making a program that you can load an image and fill the shapes in the image 3 different colors(The program is for coloring real estate plots different colors. the colors are red, green, yellow.). I can load the image, save it and draw on the picture itself, but my question is; What is the code to fill the whole shape. The shapes are random. I understand there are .FillRectangle and .FillEllipse and what not, but i need one that's a paint bucket tool. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There were a couple of relevant hits on vbforums: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?317585-Flood-Fill-Paint-Bucket-Tool and http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?482232-MS-Paint-Fill-Bucket-how-does-it-work

Comment: Alright thanks. That works, some what anyways, but when ever I go to color the plots on my jpeg, it doesn't go all the way out, it just gets a fuzzy spot filled in. All your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any functional .NET code for you but I can offer some ideas as I've worked in graphic design for many years.

A paint bucket tool works in similar fashion to a "magic wand" tool. If you're familiar with these tools in Adobe Photoshop, then you may know of some of the parameters that affect their behavior. (Tolerance, Contiguous, Anti-Alias, etc.)

When you click on a given pixel in an image, either of these tools must analyze the surrounding pixels to determine similarity. One of the options for the tool controls the threshold at which the comparison is deemed "similar" or "not similar."

Imagine you're working with a black and white (1-bit) image. If you click a white pixel, it's simple and quick to determine if that point is adjacent to any other white pixels. You would cascade the comparison out until no further white pixels were found, and fill (or select) that area.

However, now consider an 8-bit greyscale image. If you click a white (255) pixel, there may be adjacent pixels which are very light but not identical (say values 250-254). Whether these similar but not identical colors should be filled/selected should be based on a threshold of similarity.

JPG images employ a lossy compression algorithm that introduces slight variations to otherwise similar colors. This results in "fuzzy" areas which don't fill or select well using low tolerance values. You will want to allow for deviations from the original pixel by a limited amount in order to get the desired effect.

Comment: so if i were to use a picture that was never a jpeg, could that possible solve my issue?

Comment: It could help. If the areas you want to fill are identical in value you can omit the code that deals with tolerance. Some graphic formats that won't introduce variations are PNG, TIF, and BMP.